# In Javscript what is the best way to check for the existence of a (global) function

Tags: javascript, function, performance

In Javscript what is the best (most performant/fastest) way to check for the existence of a (global) function. I've used both of the following but would welcome alternatives or explanations why one method might be better than others.

Using typeof:

```
if(typeof window.myFunc != 'function'){
  window.myFunc = function(){
    // payload
  }
}
```

Defining function as existing function or creating it if it doesn't exist

```
window.myFunc == window.myFunc || function(){
  // payload
}
```

Comment: Well, the latter has a typo and won't assign anything...

Comment: Furthermore, what if `window.myFunc` is defined but not a function? Then your second approach (even with only one `=`)  won't work.

Comment: There is no problem here. Go play on [jsbench](https://jsbench.me/). Also, if you ever run into a circumstance where the performance difference between these two is meaningful enough to affect an application, please post back.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `instanceof` operator in javascript like this

```
console.log instanceof Function
```

or

```
window.foo instanceof Function
```